# select the record with the highest id value in sybase ase

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have this query

```
    SELECT      Reg.id_Movimiento, Tip.NombreTipoMov
    FROM        ut_sgt_Movimientos_t Reg
    INNER JOIN  ut_sgt_TiposMovimientos_m Tip
                ON Reg.id_TipoMov = Tip.id_TipoMov
    WHERE       Reg.id_Registro = 367
```

With this output:

```
8 Retiro
6 Marcaje
7 Porteador
5 Descarga
1 Almacenaje
```

How can i select the record with the highest id value?

I can not use subquery, set rowcount or top 1, only agregate functions, having or group by

I have tried:

```
    SELECT      Reg.id_Movimiento, Tip.NombreTipoMov
    FROM        ut_sgt_Movimientos_t Reg
    INNER JOIN  ut_sgt_TiposMovimientos_m Tip
                ON Reg.id_TipoMov = Tip.id_TipoMov
    WHERE       Reg.id_Registro = 367
    HAVING      Reg.id_Movimiento = MAX(Reg.id_Movimiento)
```

But the output is

```
8 Retiro
8 Marcaje
8 Porteador
8 Descarga
8 Almacenaje
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you specify what you cannot use, I'll assume everything else is fair game.

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1

SELECT      Reg.id_Movimiento, Tip.NombreTipoMov
FROM        ut_sgt_Movimientos_t Reg
INNER JOIN  ut_sgt_TiposMovimientos_m Tip
            ON Reg.id_TipoMov = Tip.id_TipoMov
WHERE       Reg.id_Registro = 367
ORDER BY Re.ID DESC

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the source of that constraint?

Comment: I need this select statement nested inside another select statement, and sybase don't let me use subquery, set rowcount or top 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the HAVING needs to be used with a Group By function.

```
SELECT      Reg.id_Movimiento, Tip.NombreTipoMov
FROM        ut_sgt_Movimientos_t Reg
INNER JOIN  ut_sgt_TiposMovimientos_m Tip
            ON Reg.id_TipoMov = Tip.id_TipoMov
WHERE       Reg.id_Registro = 367
GROUP FILTER rank() < 1
GROUP BY Reg.id_Movimiento, Tip.NombreTipoMov
GROUP ORDER BY Reg.id_Movimiento desc
HAVING      Reg.id_Movimiento = MAX(Reg.id_Movimiento)
```

Found a little more for Sybase

Comment: yep, i tried that before, but this is the output:                                           5      Descarga
6 Marcaje
8 Retiro
1 Almacenaje
7 Porteador

Comment: @HermanZun found a little more for Sybase, not my most used DB.